# Java 8 Streams - Iterator Map and Remove based on conditions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to figure out how I can rewrite this to use streams and filters to narrow my criteria down and remove from map if necessary.

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> iter = listOfPossibleParams.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String,Object> entry = iter.next();
    if(entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank((String) entry.getValue())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

I was initially thinking something like this, but it obiviously doesnt work as syntax errors :

```
listOfPossibleParams.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getValue() instanceof String)
            .removeIf(e -> StringUtils.isBlank((String)e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Show us your errors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you can modify the Map in place, then you could do:

```
listOfPossibleParams.values()
                    .removeIf(v -> v instanceof String && StringUtils.isBlank((String) v));
```

If you want to build a new Map instead, you could have:

```
listOfPossibleParams.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(p -> {
                        Object v = p.getValue();
                        return !(v instanceof String) || !StringUtils.isBlank((String) v);
                    })
                    .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick @Tunaki - Thanks! I thought I would of had to filter it before I could use the remove predicate. Seems to be working passing unit tests.

Comment: @Bitzal You're doing TDD, nice :)